# Flickering in Images inside GridLayout inside of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-gridlayout

I have `ScrollView` and inside I have a `GridLayout` and inside the `GridLayout` I have images, but when I scroll the Images (`ImageView`) start to flick. This only happens in API 22 or below.

My layout looks like this:

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
  android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
      app:columnCount="2"
      app:useDefaultMargins="true">


      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/img_store"
          app:layout_columnWeight="1"
          tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    <-- More images -->
  </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved, I set the view with

```
    view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```